# Cannot subscript a value of type [CLPlacemark] with an index type int

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode7

I would like to retrieve the current location. I work with on swift Xcode 7.
I looked PLUSIEUR tutorials, but every time they use the same method.
Here is my code and my error:
!

> Error : Cannot subscript a value of type [CLPlacemark] with an index
>   type int

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let LocationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.LocationManager.delegate = self
    self.LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.LocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        }
        else {
            print("errorData")
        }

    })
}

func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark){
    self.LocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    print(placemark.locality)
    print(placemark.postalCode)
    print(placemark.administrativeArea)
    print(placemark.country)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, in Xcode 7 the error is:

> error: cannot subscript a value of type '[CLPlacemark]?' with an index of type 'Int'

Note of the `?`. You have to unwrap that optional. So you can replace:

```
if placemarks!.count > 0 {
    let placemark = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
    self.displayLocationInfo(placemark)
}
```

with:

```
if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
    self.displayLocationInfo(placemark)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran across this issue in a nearly identical situation.  Again the tip off is that it thinks it isn't unpackaged so putting a ! into it worked for me.

Try this.

```
let pm = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     if placemarks!.count > 0
        {
             var pm:CLPlacemark!

            pm = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark
            //let pm:CLPlacemark = placemarks.

            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)

            let locality = (pm.locality != nil) ? pm.locality : ""

            let sublocality = (pm.subLocality != nil) ? pm.subLocality : ""

            let thoroughfare = (pm.thoroughfare != nil) ? pm.thoroughfare : ""

            let country = (pm.country != nil) ? pm.country : ""

            let administrativeArea = (pm.administrativeArea != nil) ? pm.administrativeArea : ""

            print(pm.subLocality)

            var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            annotation.title = "\(thoroughfare) \(sublocality), \(locality)"
            annotation.subtitle = "\(administrativeArea), \(country)";

            self.mapViewForVisitLocation.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
```

It work for me in X-Code 7 and Swift 2.0.