# "Cannot find an initializer for type 'MKPlaceMark' that accepts an argument list of type

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, xcode7-beta2

I am getting two errors with this code:

> "Cannot find an initializer for type 'MKPlacemark' that accepts an argument list of type '(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, addressDictionary: [NSString : String])'

and

> "Cannot invoke 'geocodeAddressstring' with an argument list of type '(String, completionHandler: ([AnyObject?]!, NSError?) -> _)'

I tried to put optionals here and there having read that it might fix things, but didn't work.

What should I change to my code to fix these errors and make my ViewController work?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import AddressBook
import Contacts
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var city: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var province: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var zip: UITextField!

    var coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    @IBAction func getDirections(sender: UIButton) {

        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

        let addressString = "\(address.text) \(city.text) \(province.text) \(zip.text)"

        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(addressString, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [AnyObject?]!, error: NSError?) in

            if error != nil {

                print("Geocode failed with error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")

            } else if placemarks?.count > 0 {

                let placemark = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                let location = placemark.location
                self.coords = location.coordinate

                self.showMap()
            }
        })
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func showMap() {
        let addressDict =[kABPersonAddressStreetKey as NSString: address.text!,
            kABPersonAddressCityKey: city.text!,
            kABPersonAddressStateKey: province.text!,
            kABPersonAddressZIPKey: zip.text! ]

        let place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coords!, addressDictionary: addressDict)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: place)
        let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]

        mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you upgrade to swift 2.0?

Swift 1.2 and before

```
geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(addressString, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [AnyObject?]!, error: NSError?) in
```

Swift 2.0

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addressString, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

And also change

```
let placemark = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
```

To

```
let placemark = placemarks[0]
```

Comment: I have indeed upgraded to Swift 2.0 and am currently using Xcode 7 beta. I am still getting errors after the changes though. On my "let placemark = ..." line, I have the error "Cannot subscript a value of type '[CLPlacemark]?' with an index of type 'Int'". And on my line "let place = ..." (in my showMap function) I am still getting the same error :S

Comment: Note: I was able to fix the "let placemark..." line error with the help of this post ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829930/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-clplacemark-with-an-index-type-int ). I should have written 'else if let placemark = placemarks?.first { '. Still have not found a fix for the error: "Cannot find an initializer for type 'MKPlacemark' that accepts an argument list of type '(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, addressDictionary: [NSString : String])'

Answer (score -1):

For the continued MKPlacemark error, try changing

`let place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coords!, addressDictionary: addressDict)`

to

```
let place = MKPlacemark.init(coordinate: coords!, addressDictionary: (addressDict as! [String:AnyObject]))
```